# Converting from Xcode Objective C tests to Google tests in C++

Tags: c++, xcode

I am converting some tests written in objective C in Xcode to C++ to work with google tests.

I know `XCTAssertTrue( variable == 1 );`
 in objective C is changed to `EXPECT_EQ(variable, 1)` for C++ for the google test.

What I am unsure about is how to convert `XCTAssertTrue( EQUALS( variable.length, 1 ) );` to C++ which would work for google tests. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In C/C++ there is `assert` (and `static_assert` since C11 / C++11), the main difference is: `assert` works at runtime and `static_assert` at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

```
EXPECT_EQ(1, variable.length);
```

or

```
ASSERT_EQ(1, variable.length);
```

note that for _EQ, the expected (constant) value goes first.